# SearchView in Android and external web site

Tags: android, search, android-intent, searchview

I have the following situation:

1. I develope my android app and I want to add "Search" inside it.
2. There is a web-site [consultant](http://www.consultant.ru/sys/english/)

This web site is about legal services that can be useful for lawyer and so on.

1. I want to connect "SearchView" inside my app with a "search" in this web site.
   In other words I want to realize search throw my app to this web site, get results from it and show in app (I think it will be ListView)

Use case: 
1

1. User open my app
2. User type his request in SearchView
3. User push the button "Search"
4. App sends this request to the web-site
5. WebSite search this request inside him (I don't know how it realized)
6. App gets result from the web-site
7. App shows result

Because I am a beginner in Android development I ask you an advice:

- Is it real?
- Can you give me links with examples describe my situation
- If it real, can you give me a code of alike realization

Thank you!
P.S my app is created like an OpenSource

P.P.S this is a search web in [this site](http://www.consultant.ru/search/) 
I see that web site uses `search/?q=`
Where after = users request

```
Example: /search/?q=codex
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by taking a look at Jsoup (http://jsoup.org/). Jsoup is a HTML Parser library with Jquery syntax. The documentation is clear and their example is easy to understand (If you familiar with Jquery).

1. First you enter keyword into EditText.
2. Click Search, append key word into url (example: /search/?q=codex)
3. use Jsoup to connect to website with that url.
4. Receive result.
5. Extract Data from result.
6. Manipulating data to your need.

That's it !

Comment: @Dmitry Boytsov: I have edited my answer to make it easier to understand. Please vote my answer if it meets your expectation.